# Why does the score increase abruptly in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, screen

I am trying to make a game in pygame, but i am getting two bugs.

## Bug 1

My score increases abruptly in the game , where my condition is to increase only 1 point at a time.
My code to increase score is:

```
 if thing_starty >display_height:
            thing_stary = 0-thing_height
            thing_startx= random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)
```

Here dodged is my score , it should increase by one every time the block goes off the screen.

## Bug 2

In my game there is a black rectangle following from top, but the thing is once it goes off the screen, it does not come back.Also after the block passes outside the screen , the game ends even if there is no collision.
The code for the block to come back is:

```
 if thing_starty >display_height: #Check if block is there in the screen or not
            thing_stary = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx= random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)
```

## Full code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

#Colours
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

#Game Display
display_width = 1080
display_height  = 720
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Eat It! ~ Snapnel Productions')

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#Font Size
exsmallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 17)
smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 80)

#Car
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carimg,(x,y))
global x, y, x_change
carimg=pygame.image.load('food.png')
#With of the car( i.e food image)
car_width=10

#Things
def things(thingx,thingy,thingw,thingh,color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,color,[thingx,thingy,thingw,thingh])

#Things doged
def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: "+str(count), True, red)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))
#Starting Of the game
def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:    
      for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key ==pygame.K_c:
                intro = False
            if event.key ==pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        #Game Initial display message
        message_to_screen("Dodge It!",
                          red,
                          -200,
                          size="large")

        message_to_screen("Press 'C' to play the game or 'Q' to quit.",
                          white,
                          150,
                          size="small")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

#Text Size
def text_objects(text,color, size):
    if size=="small":
        textSurface=smallfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="medium":
        textSurface=medfont.render(text, True ,color)
    elif size=="large":
        textSurface=largefont.render(text, True ,color)


    return textSurface,textSurface.get_rect()

#Message to screen
def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0,size="small"):
    textSurf,textRect=text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (display_width / 2),(display_height / 2)+y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

#The Game run up
def runGame():
    #global x,y, x_change
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False

    x=(display_width*0.45)    
    y=(display_height*0.48)  
    x_change =0

    #To count score
    thingCount=1
    dodged=0

    #Block Initial Size
    thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100
    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            #Game Over message

            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            message_to_screen("Game over",
                              red,
                              y_displace=-50,
                              size="large")
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit.",
                              red,
                              y_displace=50,
                              size="medium")
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()

        #Game Controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change=0

        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        things(thing_startx,thing_starty,thing_width,thing_height,black)
        thing_starty+=thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x>display_width-car_width or x<0:
            gameOver = True

        #Check if block is in the screen
        if thing_starty >display_height:
            thing_stary = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx= random.randrange(0,display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1
            thing_width += (dodged * 1.2)

        #Check Collision with block  
        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                gameOver = True

        pygame.display.update()

#The game run up
def gameLoop():
    clock.tick(FPS)
    runGame()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

[image: Here] is the food image.
Thanks in advance fellows , really , thanks to pay attention to this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your variable name, it should likely be:

```
thing_starty
```

instead of:

```
thing_stary
```

Comment: Can you tell my how to get the image down? That is i want in the bottom of my screen.

Comment: Your bug 2 code is the same as bug 1, can you update it to represent the part where it goes wrong?

Comment: my both bugs are successfully solved , but now i want that food image to be below the screen , that is at the bottom , how do i do that?

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used pygame, I just noticed your typo :) you should make a new question for that (the policy is to have only one question per 'page')